# avr-gcc calculation results varies with statement complexity

Tags: c, atmega, avr-gcc

So i have this line of  C code that takes 10-bit ADC value on the ATmega2560 and scales it to be used later by counters. results should be between 44 and 4166 or something like that

```
uint16_t tcnt = (60 * 16000000)/((100 + adc_latest * 9) * 64 * 36);
```

I compiled with avr-gcc and send the value of  tcnt to the serial to check it .. it was way outside the expected range

after checking my math and parenthesis multiple times i thought i would simplify and re-write it as follow

```
uint16_t tcnt = (416667) / (100 + adc_latest *9);
```

this time i got the expected values

can anyone explain this behavior ? is this because there is a very large intermediate value involved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're working on a 16-bit processor, and that you've been bitten by integer overflow.

I'm guessing `adc_latest` is an `int` (16 bits), or perhaps a `uint16_t`.
And the constants 100, 9, 64, and 36 are all small enough to be represented as 16-bit `int`.  So the subexpression

```
(100 + adc_latest * 9) * 64 * 36
```

will all be computed using 16-bit arithmetic.

Suppose `adc_latest` is 9000.  Then `(100 + adc_latest * 9) * 64 * 36` is 20966400 — but that's not a number you can represent in 16 bits.  So it'll overflow, with undesired and perhaps undefined results.

In the numerator, though, the constant 16000000 is already too big to be represented in 16 bits, so the compiler will implicitly treat it as a `long` int.

When you rewrote it as

```
416667 / (100 + adc_latest * 9)
```

you eliminated the overflow in the denominator, so everything worked.

If my suppositions here are correct, another fix would be

```
(60 * 16000000) / ((100 + adc_latest * 9L) * 64 * 36)
```

The simple change of `9` to `9L` will force everything in the denominator to be computed using `long` arithmetic also, eliminating overflow there and (I predict) resulting in a correct overall result.

This is all a consequence of the way expressions are evaluated "bottom up" in C.  Subexpressions get promoted to a larger, common type only when they have to be.  So in your original expression, you ended up with

```
long / int
```

At that point, the `int` in the denominator got promoted to `long` — but by then it was too late; the overflow had already occurred.  The compiler did *not* notice that since the denominator was eventually going to be promoted to `long`, it might as well evaluate the whole denominator as a `long`.  It did not evaluate the whole denominator as a `long`, so overflow in the denominator occurred.

---

Addendum: I wrote, "When you rewrote it... you eliminated the overflow in the denominator", but that was an oversimplification.  The example I gave, with `adc_latest = 9000`, works out to 81900, which is still an overflow.  So that rewrite would work for most (but not all) values of `adc_latest`, those up to 7180 or so.  So the other rewrite, forcing the entire denominator to be evaluated in 32 bits, is preferable.

There's probably some other way of rearranging the expression so that you could evaluate the whole thing using 16-bit arithmetic, if for some reason you wanted to avoid 32-bit arithmetic, but I'm not going to try to work it out just now.

Comment: thanks Steve. It is actually an 8-bit processor. and yes you are right the ADC register is 16bit wide with only 10 MSB populated ..I see what you mean though. I tried making the tcnt itself 32bit (which did not make sense to me either but whatever) but what you are saying the overflow happens because the literals ALSO have a type/size assumed and these could also overflow .. let me try you suggestions and see .. i think you are correct tho

Comment: @FadyMegally Just changing `tcnt` to 32 bits doesn't help — it's too late.

Comment: that worked! added UL to the literals .. awesome and thanks  for explaining the background.

Comment: @FadyMegally Adding `UL` to *all* the literals ins't strictly necessary — you can get away with adding it just to the `9` — but it doesn't hurt to add it to all of them.  But see the update to my answer — part of what I said at first was slightly wrong.